# Manga where the male protagonist has the power to repeat days

Tags: story-identification, manga, horror

This was a thriller/horror manga.

Something happened where the male protagonist has the power of repeating the day.

He must do something that day. I remember that there was an investigator on his tracks. The day may have repeated itself when he dies.

Comment: Was this full colour or mostly black & white? What sort of time period was the story set in? And what specifically made this a "horror" manga, as opposed to a comedy or whatnot?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_loop Are any of the stories mentioned on this page the one you're looking for?

Comment: "Time loops when he dies" sounds like Re:Zero, but thriller/horror fits it so bad that I doubt it is the answer...

Comment: If the plot like below, MC forget whenever he reset. He left his note in his room so he can keep track of what had happened. He realize that he need to survive for 7 days to escape and there is also some rule to follow. If matched please inform Sora

Answer (score -1):

This kind of sounds like Erased (Boku dake ga Inai Machi), but the protagonist re-visits his childhood to change his future.

Comment: Could you edit this answer to say a bit more about the plot, to help clarify how closely this matches the OP's description?

Comment: I've seen *Erased* and the resemblance is only vague. OP generally repeats much shorter timespans than days (and the bulk of the story happens after he jumps back to his childhood), there's no investigator on his tracks, and he doesn't die (though he *does* wind up in a coma and wake up back in the present day).

Comment: time loop manga: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_You_Need_Is_Kill . OR i'm a villager so what. OR TIME STOP BRAVE. or the one about the salaryman in japan who loops every time he dies when monsters invade japan.